# Edit span in css - Wordpress

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to edit span in CSS. It would look like:

```
span  {
font-size=20px;
color:black; }
```

So, my problem is that I don't know how to address span in this case...
Here is a Code of WordPress:

```
<div class="wcfmmp_store_tab_info wcfmmp_store_info_address"> 
        <i class="wcfmfa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span>551300708</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, edit `font-size=20px;` to `font-size: 20px` and attach code as `code`, not as image, check this: <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks>

Comment: And prefix your span so that this style doesn't bleed into everything else:

`.wcfmmp_store_tab_info span { }`

Comment: You can alternatively target that span-tag like this using the next-sibling selector: `.wcfma .fa-phone + span { }`

Comment: You might find this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

Use a more specific CSS selector for it (and use `:` instead of `=` in the `font-size` definition):

```
.wcfmmp_store_tab_info.wcfmmp_store_info_address span { 
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

This will only apply to a `span` whose *parent* has both the classes `.wcfmmp_store_tab_info` *and* `.wcfmmp_store_info_address`

Comment: I have one question: Why does not work this kind of code? ```.wcfmfa.fa-phone span { font-size: 20px; color: black; }```    This CSS is more concrete, yes?

Comment: In this case you would have to write `.wcfmfa.fa-phone + span { font-size: 20px; color: black; }`, (i.e. with a subsequent sibling selector `+`), since `span` is a subsequent *sibling* of `.wcfmfa.fa-phone`, which follows *after* it, but it is not a *child* as your selector would imply.